# Datos duplicados en una vista sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, views

Estoy haciendo una vista sql de una bitacora, el problema que estoy teniendo es que por alguna razón me esta duplicando los registros:

```
  select * from Bitacora
```

Esa es la sentencia a mi bitacora normal y me trae estos resultados

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y esta es la vista que estoy creando

```
CREATE VIEW ReporteGeneralRecorridos
AS
SELECT IdBitacora
    ,Bitacora.Estado
    ,HoraRegistro
    ,Dia
    ,NumSemana
    ,Bitacora.Latitud
    ,Bitacora.Longitud
    ,Bitacora.IdEmpresa
    ,Bitacora.IdUbicacion
    ,Bitacora.IdDispositivo
    ,TotalVueltas
    ,Empresas.Nombre AS Empresa
    ,Sucursales.Nombre AS Sucursal
    ,Dispositivos.Nombre AS Dispositivo
    ,Ubicaciones.Nombre AS Punto
    ,Ubicaciones.Contador
    ,Ubicaciones.Total
FROM Bitacora
    ,Empresas
    ,Sucursales
    ,Dispositivos
    ,Ubicaciones
WHERE Empresas.IdEmpresa = Bitacora.IdEmpresa
    AND Sucursales.IdEmpresa = Bitacora.IdEmpresa
    AND Dispositivos.IdSucursal = Sucursales.IdSucursal
    AND Ubicaciones.IdSucursal = Sucursales.IdSucursal

 GO

 SELECT IdBitacora 
 FROM ReporteGeneralRecorridos
```

Sin embargo al ejecutar la sentencia esto es lo que se esta trayendo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya intente espesificando Bitacora.IdBitacora pero el resultado es el mismo, alguien sabe que es lo que estoy omitiendo ?

Edit: para una mejor vision de todo voy a poner los datos de las otras tablas que estoy consultando

Tabla empresa
[image: TABLA EMPRESA]

Tabla sucursal
[image: TABLA SUCURSALES]

Tabla dispositivos
[image: TABLA DISPOSITIVOS]

Tabla Ubicaciones
[image: TABLA UBICACIONES]

Comment: emmm, es lo esperable cuando estás haciendo `JOINS` entre tantas tablas. De todas formas, cómo podríamos contestar sin saber los datos que contienen esas tablas?

Comment: Si es necesario puedo poner imagenes del los datos de esas tablas

Comment: mira.. sin poner datos.. todas las relaciones entre las tablas son 1 a 1??? o hay relaciones 1 a n o peor, n x m??? porque entonces, que esperas que devuelva el join de una relacion de ese tipo????

Comment: Disculpa si te parecio antipatico, pero justamente te estoy preguntando por las relaciones.. si algo no es 1 a 1 (como en la respuesta que te dieron) va a traer mas registros....

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que para cada fila de la tabla bitácora tienes asignada una empresa y cada empresa puede tener varias sucursales y cada sucursal puede tener varios dispositivos y ubicaciones.

Para corregir eso, es necesario corregir las condiciones para unir las tablas. También es importante que cambies la sintaxis para utilizar JOIN. Es un método mucho más versátil y elegante. Asigna las relaciones entre tablas en un lugar definido y lo separa de los filtros de la consulta.

```
CREATE VIEW ReporteGeneralRecorridos
AS
SELECT IdBitacora
    ,b.Estado
    ,HoraRegistro
    ,Dia
    ,NumSemana
    ,b.Latitud
    ,b.Longitud
    ,b.IdEmpresa
    ,b.IdUbicacion
    ,b.IdDispositivo
    ,TotalVueltas
    ,e.Nombre AS Empresa
    ,s.Nombre AS Sucursal
    ,d.Nombre AS Dispositivo
    ,u.Nombre AS Punto
    ,u.Contador
    ,u.Total
FROM Bitacora       b 
JOIN Empresas       e ON b.IdEmpresa     = e.IdEmpresa
JOIN Dispositivos   d ON b.IdDispositivo = d.IdDispositivo
JOIN Ubicaciones    u ON b.IdUbicacion   = u.IdUbicacion
JOIN Sucursales     s ON d.IdSucural     = s.IdSucursal
                     AND u.IdSucural     = s.IdSucursal
                     AND b.IdEmpresa     = s.IdEmpresa;
```

Comment: pero de todas formas va a haber idBitacoras repetidas en este caso, aunque se haga corractamente el JOIN...por los datos que tiene el OP

Comment: No necesariamente. La bitacora columnas de ubicación y dispositivo, por lo tanto cada fila solo tendrá una combinación de ellos. De la misma forma, cada dispositivo o ubicación solo tiene una sucursal. Solo esperemos que los datos sean correctos y la ubicación y dispositivo tengan la misma sucursal asignada.

Comment: pero una empresa tiene (o puede tener) varias sucursales

Comment: Por eso lo limitamos con las otras dos condiciones. Es posible que solo se necesite una de las 3 condiciones para el JOIN con sucursales, pero lo dejé de la forma más segura posible.